# tvOS istream failure

Tags: c++, swift, tvos

I'm trying to run the [Nestopia NES Emulation library](https://github.com/jzdziarski/nestopia/) on tvOS but every time it tries to load its database or the game file it halts here

```
void In::SafeRead(byte* data,dword size) {
    static_cast<std::istream*>(stream)->read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
}
```

Without any console output and with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0xffffffff00000000)

This is my ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let emuWidth: CGFloat = 341.0
    let emuHeight: CGFloat = 320.0

    var emulatorCore: EmulatorCore!
    var emulatorView: ScreenView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.emulatorView = ScreenView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, emuWidth, emuHeight))
        self.emulatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.emulatorView)

        self.emulatorCore = EmulatorCore()
        self.emulatorCore.initializeEmulator()
        self.emulatorCore.frameBufferSize = CGSizeMake(emuWidth, emuHeight)

        do {
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

            if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath((NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("NstDatabase.dat")) {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NstDatabase", ofType: "dat")!, toPath: (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("NstDatabase.dat"))
            }

            if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath((NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mega_man.nes")) {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mega_man", ofType: "nes")!, toPath: (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mega_man.nes"))
            }
        } catch _ {
            print("Error copying files!")
        }

        if self.emulatorCore.loadROM((NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mega_man.nes")) {
            self.emulatorCore.configureEmulator()
            self.emulatorCore.screenDelegate = self.emulatorView
            self.emulatorCore.frameBufferAddress = self.emulatorView.frameBufferAddress

            self.emulatorView.delegate = self.emulatorCore
        } else {
            print("Error: invalid game path")
        }
    }
}
```

The same code runs just fine on iOS.

Thank you!

Comment: That ViewController code doesn't look like C++. What is it? I *think* it's Swift; if so, please add a Swift tag to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I tagged the question with C++ because Nestopia is written in C++ and the error appears to be related to the library side.